# finding static file in jar

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to use a jar file which itself is a web application in another web project. In my jar which i have created using eclipse's export to jar functionality, I have stored a csv file in a folder. To use relative paths in the code in the jar I access it using

```
MyClass.class.getResource(ApplicationConstants.ALIASESFILE).getPath();
```

and this works fine when I deploy (glassfish) and use the project as a separate application. But when I am using the same from within another project, it gives a path as shown below

```
D:\javaProjects\AutomodeGS_Prachi\lib\internal\RESTWSGS.jar!\aliases\aliases.csv
```

I am getting a file notfound exception.What could be wrong?

Comment: Better you can have csv file in resource folder. If you need any changes after deployment, how it can be ?

Comment: we planned to generate the jar again. This is only one of the static files used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getResource()` method is returning a "jar:" URL.  The path component of that URL is not a normal filesystem pathname, and can't be opened directly using Java's file classes.

The simple way to do this is to use `Class.getResourceAsStream(...)` to open the stream.  If you need an "identifier" for the JAR entry, use `Class.getResource(...)`, but then open the stream using `URL.openStream()`.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine from glassfish may be because glassfish has exploded jar on file system so that your csv file is acutually a file to the file system,

if you try to read it from another project it fails because the jar containing your file is in classpath that is fine, but the csv file is under jar file and it is no longer a `File`

You can read it as Stream

```
InputStream is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(ApplicationConstants.ALIASESFILE);
```

Comment: same as above answer hence increasing number for usefullness! Thanks a lot

Comment: you didn't notice time or answer posted :)